# terraform import AWS s3 bucket with dot in name

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to import a bucket into the tfstate that has a dot in its name by using the command:

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.example.com example.com
```

bucket name is example.com
my resource is built like this

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example.com" {
}
```

regarding the import I get this error:

> Unexpected extra operators after address.

and tried to escape it with `\` but didn't work. As for the resource, how can I escape it? since it tells me name should only have numbers digits dash and hyphen ....

Comment: the resource name doesnt have to match the actual bucket name. The bucket name is provided as string inside the resource with the key *bucket*.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why it does not work?

Answer (score 3):

`example.com` is an **invalid name**. You can't have `.` in a resource name in TF. You can only use:

> letters, digits, underscores, and dashes